# Google maps marker snippet not supporting iOS Dark mode

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, ios-darkmode

Google maps iOS SDK doesn't seem to take care of the new Dark mode.

Having issue with white background/white label:

[image: Dark mode: problem]

While regular light mode is working as expected:

[image: Light mode: OK]

Any known work-arounds?

Comment: I have not found a workaround, yet. As every day the iOS 13 dark mode user community grows, this effect/bug gets more important to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed in **GoogleMaps 3.5.0**!

Comment: I installed that version and it didn't work for me through CocoaPods. Should I apply some missing steps? How did you fix it?

Comment: @JesúsCastro just updated and it worked! Try rebuilding the project...

Comment: This happened to me also, i fixed it by updating GoogleMaps. Thanks @Alexander

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `tracksInfoWindowChanges` property of the `GMSMarker` to be true. 
By default, it is `false`.

`tracksInfoWindowChanges` controls whether the info window for marker should be redrawn every frame.

Simple code for creating the map marker will look like this:

```swift
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
```